# FSCalendar - Change bg color of selected dates Swift 3?

Tags: swift3

I am using FSCalendar to add calendar UI in my project. 
But I am unable to find any solution to change bg color of some selected  dates. 
Can anyone suggest me how change color of selected dates in FSCalendar in swift 3?

```
import FSCalendar
  fileprivate weak var calendar: FSCalendar!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // In loadView or viewDidLoad
    let calendar = FSCalendar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 300))
    calendar.dataSource = self
    calendar.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(calendar)
    self.calendar = calendar

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please follow the steps.

1). Add delegate FSCalendarDelegateAppearance

2). Below is my reference array. You should have yours

```
let selectedDates = ["2017/01/08", "2017/01/06", "2017/01/17"]
```

3). Add your date formatter

```
fileprivate lazy var dateFormatter1: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
    return formatter
}()
```

3). select the dates using

```
calendar.select(self.dateFormatter1.date(from: "2017/01/08"))
```

4). Add delegate method for color change.

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, appearance: FSCalendarAppearance, fillSelectionColorFor date: Date) -> UIColor? {

    let dateString = self.dateFormatter1.string(from: date)

    if self.selectedDates.contains(dateString) {
        return UIColor.green
    }

    return appearance.selectionColor
}
```

5). Now Run it. :)

Comment: Thanks, But i wanted to ad color corresponding to date like 1,2,3 etc

Comment: Means some default date background color want to be change

Comment: Do you have array of selected dates ? and for that particular dates you want to fill the color ?

Comment: Yes i have array of date, Corresponding to date i want to change bg color.
http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/FSCalendar/0.11.2/ following this article.

Comment: Can you suggest me how to show multiple selected date?

Comment: Please inform me for how to default show multiple date?

Comment: you may use "willDisplay" delegate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132676/discussion-between-saleem-khan-and-nikunj-damani).